# How is Instagram's or Facebook feed works in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, instagram, ios10

I'm building an iOS client for a new social network service based on music. It will have a part where user will interact with a 'feed' of news. What is the most convenient approach in building this feed? Should I ask a server for a, like 20 last posts or so? And when user scrolls to the end of first 20 posts I should ask for another 20? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is normally referred to as pagination.

On the back end the data is broken up into chunks. The iOS client will them make some GET request like

> www.myAPI.com/feed?page=1

to get the initial chunk of 20 items. Then before the user finishes scrolling to the bottom make another call

> www.myAPI.com/feed?page=2

and merge and append results to the tableview.

If you're interested in how Facebook creates such fast tableview consider looking into: https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit